# Get simple text in body

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to get plain text in the body tag.

Markup:

```
**simple text 1**
<div>------</div>
<font>-------</font>
**simple text 2**
```

Code:

```
foreach (HtmlElement elm in webBrowser1.Document.Body.All)
{
    //get simple text
}
```

Comment: WebBrowser is .net control

Comment: What's wrong with `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this easy way :

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
foreach (var elm in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
{
    if (elm.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        //simple text is #text
        var innerText=elm.InnerText;
    }  
}
```

have a good time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
string plainText = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following way:**  you can get all text which are shown in browser preview by using following technique.

```
        string plainText= StripHTML(webBrowser1);// call this way-----

        public string StripHTML(WebBrowser webp)
        {
            try
            {
                Clipboard.Clear();
                webp.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", true, null);
                webp.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ep.Message);
            }
            return Clipboard.GetText();            
        }
```